# Enemy damaging with regen system

Tags: c++, beginner, windows, battle-simulation

Small project i made to practice my c++, im a beginner and want to know all about optimizing code.

Enemy starts off with 10 HP and we can damage them for 1 HP by pressing F1,
If their HP is below their max they regenerate 1 point each second.

````
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int maxHP = 10;
    int enemyHp = maxHP;
    cout << "Enemy HP: " << enemyHp << '\n';
    while (enemyHp > 0)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1) & 1)
        {
            enemyHp--;
            system("CLS");
            cout << enemyHp << '\n';
        }
        static int sec = time(NULL);
        int secNew = time(NULL);
        int* secPtr = &sec;

        if (sec != secNew)
        {
            if (enemyHp < maxHP)
            {
                enemyHp++;
                system("CLS");
                cout << enemyHp << '\n';
            }
            *secPtr = secNew;
        }

        if (enemyHp == 0)
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Enemy has died.\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: We don't spell it [java.net.http.HTTPRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html) -- prefer `maxHp`, consistent with `enemyHp`. There's two tests for zero hit points -- move the "has died" so it's outside the `while` loop. Break out a helper() to display current hit points, as we do it in several places, or better: just display it at **one** point in the loop. Read about ANSI [escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences) to avoid the expensive system() call.

Answer (score 2):

Don't write `using namespace std;`.

`maxHP` should be `constexpr` or at least `const`.  In general, use `const` where you can.